# Google My Maps pins showing on Android but not iOS

Tags: ios, google-maps, mymaps

I have created several maps for my company using Google My Maps. Within the last few days, the people using IOS devices are able to see the list of all the created maps, in the My Places > Maps section, as well as the map information via the map legend. However the pins and selected background image on the map are not showing up. On Android phones and on PC the maps work and load normally. We're only experiencing issues on IOS devices.

I've tried deleting and reinstalling the app. I've tried signing in and out. I went to Settings > About, terms & privacy > Clear application data.

What's my next step?

Answer (score 4):

Same happening here :( both of us have iPhones - we can view our list ‘legend’ but the pins aren’t showing on the map - hope Apple fix this issue soon!!